# Modifying CSS for GWT App

Tags: html, css, gwt

Using a GWT web app, Firebug says that the following HTML

```
<table class="drop-zone drop-zone-column-66 multi-zone">
...
</table>
```

is using this CSS.

```
.maximized-gadget .drop-zone.multi-zone, .configure-tab a {
    display: block;
}
```

What CSS do I need to write so that this `<table>` will have style, `display: none`?

I made 2 attempts: **[EDIT - updated .multi-zone and display:none]**

```
.drop-zone .drop-zone-column-66 .multi-zone {
    display: none;
}
```

and

```
.maximized-gadget .drop-zone.multi-zone, .configure-tab a {
    display: none;
}
```

but Firebug still gives me the CSS shown at the top.

Please advise me.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, all you should need is:

```
.maximized-gadget .drop-zone.multi-zone {
    display: none;
}
```

provided that that rule comes after the original rule you gave above:

```
.maximized-gadget .drop-zone.multi-zone, .configure-tab a {
    display: block;
}
```

Depending on what the structure of the rest of your document is and what you're trying to do, you may need to add some specificity to that rule.

The problem with your first attempt is that your rule would apply to an element with a class of `multi-zone` which is a descendant of an element of class `drop-zone-column-66`, which in turn is a descendant of an element of class `drop-zone`. What you want is to target an element that has all three of those classes set on it, which you can do by chaining those selectors:

```
.drop-zone.drop-zone-column-66.multi-zone {
    display: none;
}
```

which should set you right (though if I remember correctly this won't work in older versions of IE).

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the whole thing, you're trying to set `display: none` on your table, but in both of your attempts above you have it as `display: block`, which is how it's already set

Comment: My fault - another typo. I mistakenly wrote 'display: block' rather than 'display: none' Also, I tried both of your recommendations, but neither worked for me. I'm thinking it's possible for a "!important" to be screwing me up. The team I'm on has used them before as workaround hacks.

Comment: yeah, `!important` can end up biting you in the ass, it should definitely be avoided.

Comment: Well, I take back what I said about '!important.' I just checked my CSS, and I did not see any '!important' keywords in any of my affected classes' CSS.

Comment: And you're sure the new rule is after the original rule in the cascade?

Comment: This updated style lives at the very bottom of my core.css. It's Firefox conditional css since it renders my page poorly with my given CSS, shown above.